# How do I create a locale backup from my mongo DB in Atlas?

Tags: mongodb

I've been searching for a way to make a backup and while the page seems to have much information I can't find a way to backup the db from Atlas to my locale. The closest I've found is the `mongodump` command but what would I have to indicate if it's even possible with this command?

Comment: Did you try? I don't see any reason why it should not work.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit but to where should I point the host and port?

Comment: How do you connect to the MongoDB Atlas? Just use the same connection string URI for mongodump (mongoexport should also work)